# MATLAB’s extractBetween alternative for Octave in cell array

Tags: matlab, octave, compatibility, substr, cell-array

I am trying to run a MATLAB code in Octave. There is a MATLAB function [`extractBetween`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/extractbetween.html?searchHighlight=extractBetween&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) that is not yet available in octave. Original code is

```
numbers = str2double(extractBetween(dirAndFileNames(:,2), 4, 5));
```

I have tried to replace it with this code.

```
numbers = str2double(substr(dirAndFileNames(:,2), 4, 2));
```

It works for single strings but not for cell arrays. I have tried other functions that work with cell arrays like `strtrim`, `strtrunc`. I want to extract the numbers on the end but `strtrunc` gives opposite of what I want. It gives the first letters.

`dirAndFilenames(:,2)` looks like this:

```
debug> dirAndFileNames(:,2)
ans =
{
  [1,1] = desktop.ini
  [2,1] = trn01
  [3,1] = trn02
  [4,1] = trn03
  [5,1] = trn04
  [6,1] = trn05
  [7,1] = trn06
  [8,1] = trn07
  [9,1] = trn08
  [10,1] = trn09
  [11,1] = trn10
}
```

Comment: Did you try writing a loop over the strings in the cell array? You can use the function `cellfun` if you want to hide the explicit loop.

Comment: I tried but I am new to matlab code.

Comment: for i = 1:length(dirAndFileNames)
      numbers{i} = str2double(substr(dirAndFileNames(i,2){1}, 4, 2))
    end

Answer (score 2):

As @cris suggested, i had to loop over.

```
for i = 1:length(dirAndFileNames) 
    numbers{i} = str2double(substr(dirAndFileNames(i,2){1}, 4, 2)) 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cellindexmat](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/cellindexmat.html) :

```
a = dirAndFileNames(:, 2);
result = cellindexmat(a, 4:5);
```